# jQuery display form alert box

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate, alert

Hi i'm trying to display an alert or style-able popup box that says Empty Fields when the submit button is press. The code below stopped working after I added `alert("Empty Fields!!");`

```
var validator = $("#reg_form").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: $("#reg_form div.error"),
    meta: "validate",
    alert("Empty Fields!!");
});
```

Comment: Please show your HTML for the benefit of future readers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume that http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate is the jQuery plugin that your code referes  to.

You can't use alert in class declaration. You will have to rewrite it like this:

```
var validator = $("#reg_form").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: $("#reg_form div.error"),
    meta: "validate",
    submitHandler: function( form ) {
        alert("Empty Fields!!");
    }
});
```

or use invalidHandler: function(form, validator) instead of submitHandler

Comment: `submitHandler` prevents and replaces the browser's default `submit` handler when the form validates successfully so I guess the error messages should be in `invalidHandler`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm posting this, after another answer was accepted, for the benefit of future readers since the other answers seem to each contain some technical errors and lack explanation.

---

You cannot simply insert JavaScript into `.validate()` when it only accepts its predefined options in the form of `key:value` pairs.  See the documentation for all available options:  http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions.

As you can see, you'd need to assign `alert("Empty Fields!!");` into a `function` on one of the available `callback` handlers.  Since the message is `Empty Fields!!`, I'll choose the `invalidHandler` callback option.  [As per the docs](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/validate#toptions), `invalidHandler` is the:  *"Callback for custom code when an **invalid** form is submitted."*

Conversely, `submitHandler:` is the: *"Callback for handling the actual submit when the form is **valid**."* ~ Since the message contains `Empty Fields!!`, you wouldn't want to show that on a valid form.

It's also a good idea to enclose your `.validate()` within a `document.ready` function to ensure the HTML form is fully constructed when the plugin is initialized.

**Working DEMO:  http://jsfiddle.net/QYCwH/**

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var validator = $("#reg_form").validate({
        errorLabelContainer: $("#reg_form div.error"),
        meta: "validate",
        invalidHandler: function(form, validator) {
            alert("Empty Fields!!");
        }
    });
});
```

---

**Just to note:**  In this case, there is nothing useful about assigning `.validate()` to a variable called `validator`.  Since `.validate()` should only be called *once* on DOM ready to *initialize the plugin*, you would not need to ever reference it again, so there's really no advantage to having it assigned to a variable.

If you need to trigger a validation test of the form or need a boolean value of the form's present status, simply use [the `.valid()` method](http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation/valid).

```
$("#reg_form").valid();  // triggers a validation check without having to submit
```

or

```
if ($("#reg_form").valid()) { ...  // tests to see if the form is valid
```

Answer (score 1):

friend for your future reference

validate is accepting a json string which should be of format {'key1':'value1','key1':'value1'}, so there must be a semicolon between key value and key-value pairs are seperated by comma, so please use it as key-value pair i.e {'error':function(){alert('hello');}}

Comment: yes, but I just gave him some clarity about json string, not meant to say use it exactly with error, Hopefully he might not use alert in the place of key value pairs :), which will be helpful through out jquery usage.
Expecting some suggestion from you to accomodate the requirement, as per your reputation!.

Comment: My suggestion would be to look at how the other answers are formatted and strive for accuracy, explanation, and clarity.  If you only mean to give the OP a small suggestion, then it should be reserved as a comment instead of an answer.

Comment: Right, Hopefully my information might be help him, it is covering some part of later two, and definitely your information is helpfull to me. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

```
var validator = $("#reg_form").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: $("#reg_form div.error"),
    meta: "validate",
    error: function(){alert("Empty Fields!!")};
});
```

Just replace that `error` property with appropriate one...

UPDATE ::

Just checked jQ docs...

replace `error` handler with `submitHandler`

```
var validator = $("#reg_form").validate({
    errorLabelContainer: $("#reg_form div.error"),
    meta: "validate",
    submitHandler: function(myForm){alert("Empty Fields!!")};
});
```

Comment: If you read the documents further, `submitHandler:` is a callback that only fires when the form is _valid_.  So that really doesn't make any sense given the message, _"Empty Fields"_.